# Update to remove double quotes from number jsonb postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select, jsonb

I am using PostgreSQL and I am trying to run an update for jsonb.

I want "2W" to change to just the number 2.

So the query below removes the W, but leaves it as "2".

How I would go about removing the double quotes ?

currently it looks like {"size": "2W"} and I would like it to look like {"size": 2}

```
UPDATE x
SET x = jsonb_set(x, '{size}', ('"' || replace(x->>'size', 'W', '') || '"')::jsonb)
WHERE x IN ('')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_jsonb()` for this:

```
jsonb_set(x, '{size}', to_jsonb(replace(x->>'size', 'W', '')::int))
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dc9a1e58ada40579ee753a790b2bb3ae)**:

```
select jsonb_set(x, '{size}', to_jsonb(replace(x->>'size', 'W', '')::int))
from (values('{"size": "2W"}'::jsonb)) as t(x)
```

```
| jsonb_set   |
| :---------- |
| {"size": 2} |
```

You can replace `::int` with `::numeric` to handle decimal values if needed.